# How to load a video from my Sony TX7 Camera to YouTube

Tags: webapp-rec, avi

I notice that the format for the video my camera takes is not AVI or MPEG. The output video file is .mts (AVCHD).

Are there are free converters for this (to convert to AVI)?

After googling around the only software I can find is stuff you have to pay for.

Comment: What Operating System are you on?

Answer (score 0):

There is [**MediaCoder**](http://www.mediacoderhq.com), but you'll need to figure out the 'recipe' for conversion.
Here is [one reference on its forums](http://forum.mediacoderhq.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=9488&p=28837#p28837).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)? If it can play it, it can transcode it.

Answer (score 0):

[**Freemake Video Converter**](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/) supports .mts files and is under active development.  Free, reliable and has very simple drag and drop functionality.

> 200+ Input Formats
>
> Free Video Converter accepts any input video file: AVI, MP4, MKV, WMV, MPG, 3GP, 3G2, SWF, FLV, TOD, AVCHD, MOV, DV, RM, QT, TS, **MTS**, etc. Import music (MP3, AAC, WMA, WAV), and photos (JPG, BMP, PNG,GIF) to turn them into video free and easily! 200+ supported formats

It also has a button that uploads straight to YouTube as part of the conversion process.

Answer (score 0):

As per [YouTube help](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=55744) they accept the following video formats:

> - Windows Media Video(.AVI)
> - .3GP (mobile phones)
> - .WMV (windows)
> - .MOV (mac)
> - .MP4 (iPod/PSP)
> - .MPEG
> - .FLV (Adobe Flash)
> - .MKV (h.264)

Quickest way from .mts to YouTube is probably to use [eac3to](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=125966) and then run with the following command paramaters:

```
eac3to input.mts output.mkv
```

See the [Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Eac3to/How_to_Use#Command_Line_Syntax) for further info. Also, if you don't already have it you will need [Haali Media Splitter](http://haali.su/mkv/)